# How does Service Pack 3 for Excel 2007 show up in "About"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

That is, if you know for a fact that SP3 for Excel 2007 has been installed, how does notation of its existence in your system read out under Office Button!Excel Options!Resources!about Microsoft Office Excel 2007?

For example, apparently I have Excel 2007 SP2, judging from my readout which states:

```
Microsoft Office Excel 2007 (12.0.6654.5003) SP2 MSO (12.0.6562.5003)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has a fantastic KB article about this ([KB928116](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928116)).

Depending on the exact edition of Office (or Excel), you're looking at a build number from this list (based on my initial glance):

- 12.0.6607.1000
- 12.0.6606.1000
- 12.0.6611.1000

Lower down the page it goes on to say that this build number will appear in the same manner as your provided example. So expect to see something like:

`Microsoft Office Excel 2007 (12.0.6611.1000) SP3 MSO (12.0.6606.1000)`

Comment: Always glad to help!